# Neural Network Process - Updating weights after each training set

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

When creating a neural network, do I update the weights after each run of forward then back propogation? Or do I just keep the random weights and update the Delta variables?

I am looking at slide 8 on these notes:https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/ml/docs/slides/Lecture9.pdf

It says:

```
For i = 1 to m  
 Set a(1) = x(i)  
 Perform Forward-Propogation  
 Compute delta
 Compute DELTA
 QUESTION: Do I update the Weights that I use in Forward-propogation, or do I 
 use random weights and just keep updating the accumulator 'DELTA'? And if I 
 update the weights, do I set them to DELTA?
```

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?  This seems like a pretty legitimate question.. What should I add/edit?

Comment: Ask yourself: if you kept the random weights, why would you be training in the first place? How would the loss function, and its partial derivatives, change over the iterations?

Comment: I assumed that I updated the weights, but seeing that it wasn't on the notes page, I thought maybe the different inputs would make the difference I guess.  I was initially under the impression that I updated the weights to the lower case delta variable, but do I use the accumulator 'DELTA' as the new weights?

Comment: The notes describe the backprop algorithm, which only computes the partial derivatives. It doesn't update anything. Somewhere in Ng's notes and videos must be a description of the actual training algorithm that you build from backprop.

Comment: Ok, I'll look for that, thanks

Comment: In case anyone else has the same question, this link was also very helpful: http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html